What does 'precision' exactly mean in the binance api?
I am using python ccxt to place a sell order on binance.
order = exchange.create_order(symbol, 'market', 'sell', amount)

I have fetched the required precision, and got 5.
markets = exchange.load_markets()
amount_precision = market['precision']['amount']

So, I set the precision of amount, which was originally 0.0002535009794671468384415698887 to 5, and got 0.00025.
But when I create an order with this amount value, I get the error:
binance amount of BTC/USDT:USDT must be greater than minimum amount precision of 3

Although I have set the precision to 5, which was the required value.
What does precision really mean in the binance api? Is it the number of significant digits? I need some clarification.

you may have to ask admins of bitcoin portal

maybe ask on similar portal https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/

0.00025 is less than the minimum amount precision of 3 ,  minimum amount meeting that constraint would be 0.001 . But, as mentioned, feedback from the bitcoin forum.

you can use the following code to calculate the quantity
market_data = exchange.market(symbol) # load info for your symbol
precision = market_data['precision']['amount']
min_order_amount = market_data['limits']['amount']['min'] # useful to avoid to trigger low amount error
# Determine the number of decimal places from the precision value
precision_decimal_places = max(0, int(-math.log10(precision))) # if precision is a float
precision_decimal_places = len(precision) - 2 #if precision is str (-2 to remove 0.)
# Ensure the quantity is within the allowed precision and limits
quantity = max(min_order_amount, round_down(quantity, precision_decimal_places))


